# C++ signed and unsigned int vs long long speed

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation

Today, I noticed that the speed of several simple bitwise and arithmetic operations differs significantly between `int`, `unsigned`, `long long` and `unsigned long long` on my 64-bit pc.

In particular, the following loop is about twice as fast for `unsigned` as for `long long`, which I didn't expect.

```
int k = 15;
int N = 30;
int mask = (1 << k) - 1;
while (!(mask & 1 << N)) {
    int lo = mask & ~(mask - 1);
    int lz = (mask + lo) & ~mask;
    mask |= lz;
    mask &= ~(lz - 1);
    mask |= (lz / lo / 2) - 1;
}
```

(full code [here](https://gist.github.com/RagnarGrootKoerkamp/ed876916d14d097973f2))

Here are the timings (in seconds) (for `g++ -O`, `-O2` and `-O3`):

```
1.834207723 (int)
3.054731598 (long long)
1.584846237 (unsigned)
2.201142018 (unsigned long long)
```

These times are very consistent (i.e. a 1% margin).
Without `-O` flag, each one is about one second slower, but the relative speeds are the same.

Is there a clear reason for this?
Vectorization might be it for the 32-bit types, but I can't see where the huge
difference between `long long` and `unsigned long long` comes from.
Are some operations just much slower on some types than on others,
or is it just a general thing that 64-bit types are slower (even on 64-bit architectures)?

For those interested, this loop loops over all subsets of `{1,2,...,30}` with exactly 15 elements. This is done by looping (in order) over all integers less than `1<<30` with exactly 15 bits set.
For the current case, that's [155117520](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30+choose+15) iterations.
I don't know the source of this snippet anymore, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495102/iterate-through-different-subset-of-size-k) post explains some more.

## Edit

It seems from the assembly code that the division can be made faster when the type is unsigned. I think that makes sense, because we don't have to account for the sign bit.

Furthermore, the 32-bit operations use `movl` and other `xxxl` instructions,
while the 64-bit operations use `movq` and `xxxq`.

## Edit 2

After reading the post I linked, I decided to use the formula given over there:

```
T k = 15;
T N = 30;
T mask = (1 << k) - 1;
while (!(mask & 1 << N)) {
    T t = mask | (mask - 1);
    mask = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(mask) + 1));
}
```

This runs in about a third of the time of the code posted above, and uses the same time for all four types.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly?

Comment: Well, assembly is not something I really excel in, but it might be worth a try

Comment: Double-check your binary is x64?

Comment: @jmnben `file ./a.out` starts with `ELF 64-bit` and `x86-64`, so that seems right.

Comment: Intel Compiler is smart enough to optimize the calculations at compile time - the execution time is 0 seconds.

Comment: I am probably too lazy to check it myself (since I dont know what exactly you are doing inside the loop) but, are you sure that the loops have the same *number of calculations* in every case? Moreover, you cannot draw such a conclusion with a test that runs only once, you'd probably have to embed each case inside a wider loop, to have more serious results. BTW it is hard to believe that your simple test case takes many seconds :o

Comment: @A.S.H I'll edit the post to explain what the loop actually does.

Comment: @A.S.H, the number of calculations is the same. The variable mask does not take values that cannot be fit in 0 .. 2^31-1 range.

Comment: see [also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5069643/3288910).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slowest operation in your code is

```
mask |= (lz / lo / 2) - 1
```

32-bit division is significantly faster than 64-bit division. For example, on Ivy Bridge, 32 bit IDIV takes 19-26 clocks while 64 bit IDIV takes 28-103 clocks latency.

The unsigned version is also faster than signed because the division by 2 is simple bit shift in the unsigned case and there is no size expansion calls (CDQ, CQO).

in the unsigned case is simple bit shift while in signed

[1] http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: You probably mean "...is significantly faster..."

Comment: After using code without a division, all four types use the same speed. Also, the assembly was pretty much the same apart from the division instruction, so I guess you're right.